# Convert u03C0 or u2026C to char?

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii

I wanted to convert a ascii to a char. If that is what I think.

I want to convert something like u03C0 to the actual symbol, which is PI.

Can this be done with control characters too? Like u206C?

Put a control character in a char or a string. Can I do this?

Comment: you mean you have a string with that code?  Like `string s = "u03C0";`?

Comment: Ya, I do. I want to convert that string to its actual symbol

Comment: Also `u2026C` i not unicode because it's more than 2 bytes . Do you mean `u2026`?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant u206C.

Comment: You can do it, just don't expect it to print something meaningful (it may not even be visible).  It is a control character after all.

Comment: How would I? @sstan?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the hex string to a `long` and to a `char` form there:

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt64("03C0",16))
```

You can strip the `u` however you like - using `Replace`, `Substring`, etc.

Comment: @csharpguy231 15 Years of experience with .NET (and reading the documentation of Convert.ToChar) :)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this if you want:

```
char c = '\u206C';
```

or

```
string s = "\u206C";
```

But if you try to display it, you won't see anything.  It's not a visible character.

Comment: This is the best solution if the characters are meant to be used in *string literals*.